# Error 8000 - Installing Ubuntu on an old PC with bootable DVD

Tags: 12.04, installation, dvd

Is there an ISO file with less than 700 MB?
I cannot put the ISO file 'ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386' with 707 MB on CD having only 700 MB. 
I tried to make a bootable DVD but when booting PC says:

> EDD: Error 8000 reading sector 50

(and then 51,52,53 etc) and then **boot failed ..**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to burn with another CD but do not use CD-RW (it might be a faulty burned disc).

You can find CD releases for 12.04 here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ But you do need an 80 minutes CD (those are a bit over 700M).

- Do you have an USB port on the machine? If so see: "[How to create a bootable USBstick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)" as an alternative.
- Another method: download the server and manually add the desktop. Server is 665M so will fit.

Oh and as of 12.10 a CD is no longer an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install [the 11.10](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso) an older version of Ubuntu (695MB), and then update & upgrade & dist-upgrade the system.